# cURL request in Swagger?

Tags: curl, swagger

I am new to Swagger. I want to ask a question. I have a docker on the server with a neural network that processes the photo! To send a photo to the docker for processing, I use the string "curl http: // localhost: 5000 / predict -X POST -F" image=@1201.jpg" to the terminal I tried to send this command along with the photo through the postman, and everything worked, but I want to try to do it through Swagger. This is possible ??? I wrote a form for downloading phtographs, but I cannot send a command (curl http: // localhost: 5000 / predict -X POST -F "image=@1201.jpg" ) Can you help?

```html
 version: 1.0.0
# host: api.example.com
# basePath: /v1
# schemes:
#   - http
# host: 192.168.0.1:5000
# basePath: /predikt
paths:
   /upload:
     post:
       responses:
        '200':
          description: OK
       summary: Uploads a file.
       consumes:
         - multipart/form-data
       parameters:
        - in: formData
          name: upfile
          type: file
          required: true
          description: The file to upload.
        - in: formData
          name: note
          type: string
          required: false
          description: Description of file contents.
```

Comment: What tool do you use to send the request (Swagger UI? something else?) and what exactly do you mean by "cannot send a command"? Do you get an error? If so, what is the error message?

Comment: The problem is that I do not understand how to send this command, I have read a lot of documentation on svagger, but I did not understand how to send this command